# Can't Get Navigation Menu slideToggle to Work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am fairly new to javascript in web design and can't seem to figure out even after quite a bit of research how to properly get my navigation menu to **slidetoggle and push the content below it up and down**. Ideally, if I could get some help on *getting the menu to appear as wide as the container below it* so things look even that would be great.

I don't have the slideToggle code in the jsfiddle, but here is one of the things i tried:

```
$("#menu-button").click(function() {
    $("a").slideToggle(1000);
});
```

Here is the fiddle of the current setup of my code: https://jsfiddle.net/3uag19p1/18/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the structure of the HTML to this:

```
<body id="page">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <header id="masthead">
      <div class="container header-container">
        <div class="site-branding">
          <h1 class="site-title">
            <a href="#home" rel="home">Logo</a>
          </h1>
        </div>

        <nav class="site-navigation" id="myTopnav">
          <a href="#home">Home</a>
          <a href="#business">Business</a>
          <a href="#background">Background</a>
          <a href="#info">Info</a>
          <a href="#login">Login</a>

        </nav>
                <a id="menu-button" href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
      </div>
    </header>

    <div id="content">
      <main class="container content-padding">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras sem nibh, porttitor quis interdum sed, eleifend non eros. Quisque vitae augue mi. Etiam eget ligula volutpat purus dictum porttitor. Cras eleifend quam sit amet venenatis finibus. Aliquam sagittis lacus quis aliquet consequat. Pellentesque sed placerat sem, eu auctor enim. Curabitur ante lorem, ornare eget bibendum vitae, posuere at tortor. Etiam sit amet neque in nulla molestie rutrum sed ac urna. Vivamus enim tellus, interdum a eleifend at, laoreet in nisl. Etiam condimentum, arcu id lobortis tempus, justo turpis varius nisi, a mollis nulla risus et augue. Donec rutrum, erat in aliquet eleifend, leo risus imperdiet velit, ut feugiat lacus nulla iaculis orci. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nam eu odio sem. Aliquam id ullamcorper dolor, quis dapibus lacus. Fusce eu lorem ac ipsum condimentum pellentesque a et velit.</p>
      </main>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Then style the menu button so that it appears on the right side of the page:

```
#menu-button {
    position: absolute;
    right: 30px;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

To make the menu appear as wide as the container, make the width to 100%:

```
.site-navigation {
    float: right;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Preview it here: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chiragbhansali/3uag19p1/51/)

Comment: Can't believe i didn't think about taking the button out of the nav. Your code does almost exactly what I want. There are a few formatting errors, but all things I can easily fix. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I updated for you the structure of html. You need to place `#menu-button` outside to make sure it always visible

```
<a id="menu-button" href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
        <nav class="site-navigation" id="myTopnav">
          <a href="#home">Home</a>
          <a href="#business">Business</a>
          <a href="#background">Background</a>
          <a href="#info">Info</a>
          <a href="#login">Login</a>

        </nav>
```

And for the problem with **slidetoggle and push the content below it up and down**, you just use `position: absolute`. Don't add position for `.site-navigation a`. This will make the position go wrong.

```
.site-navigation {
    position: absolute;
   right: -100px;
   top: 100px;
   transition: all 0.3s;

    width: 100px;
}

.site-navigation.responsive {
  right: 51px;
}
```

Use `overflow-x: hidden` to hide the menu to make sure we don't have scroll to see this menu

```
#page {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #1c222b;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

I added animation to make this go smoothly

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3uag19p1/45/)

Comment: Can't believe i didn't think about taking the button out of the nav. Your code doesn't appear to push the content, just overlay it, but either way it does look nice. You are making me reconsider what type of action I want the menu to perform and I may end up going with the overlay. Didn't quite do what I was looking for, but thanks anyways!